# How to retrieve a list of facebook messenger subscribers of my page using facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger

I am working on a feature that will do broadcasting message for users that subscribed to our messenger, the feature will need to show the users who subscribe to our messenger. I've been reading Facebook docs, but there is no mention on api that will list all users that subscribed. My page had subscribed to Advanced Messaging Features ( subscription message ).

[image]

Help! How can I retrieve a list of subscribers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to store the users in your Database to have a list. But broadcasting can be done with the Broadcasting API anyway: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/broadcast-api/